# Changing part of a column name in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of columns that I want to rename a portion of based on a list of values.

I am looking at a file which has 12 months of data and each month is a different column (I need to keep it in this specific format unfortunately). This file is generated once per month and I keep the column names more general since I have to do a lot of calculations on them based the month number (for example, I need to compare information against the average of month 8, 9, and 10 every month).

Here are the columns I want to rename:

```
['month_1_Sign',
 'month_2_Sign',
 'month_3_Sign',
 'month_4_Sign',
 'month_5_Sign',
 'month_6_Sign',
 'month_7_Sign',
 'month_8_Sign',
 'month_9_Sign',
 'month_10_Sign',
 'month_11_Sign',
 'month_12_Sign',
 'month_1_Actual',
 'month_2_Actual',
 'month_3_Actual',
 'month_4_Actual',
 'month_5_Actual',
 'month_6_Actual',
 'month_7_Actual',
 'month_8_Actual',
 'month_9_Actual',
 'month_10_Actual',
 'month_11_Actual',
 'month_12_Actual',
 'month_1_Target',
 'month_2_Target',
 'month_3_Target',
 'month_4_Target',
 'month_5_Target',
 'month_6_Target',
 'month_7_Target',
 'month_8_Target',
 'month_9_Target',
 'month_10_Target',
 'month_11_Target',
 'month_12_Target']
```

Here are the names I want to place:

```
required_date_range = sorted(list(pd.Series(pd.date_range((dt.datetime.today().date() + pd.DateOffset(months=-13)), periods=12, freq='MS')).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')))

['2015-03-01',
 '2015-04-01',
 '2015-05-01',
 '2015-06-01',
 '2015-07-01',
 '2015-08-01',
 '2015-09-01',
 '2015-10-01',
 '2015-11-01',
 '2015-12-01',
 '2016-01-01',
 '2016-02-01']
```

So month_12 columns (month_12 is always the latest month) would be changed to '2016-02-01_Sign', '2016-02-01_Actual', '2016-02-01_Target' in this example.

I tried doing this but it doesn't change anything (trying to change the month_# with the actual date it refers to):

```
final.replace('month_10', required_date_range[9], inplace=True)
final.replace('month_11', required_date_range[10], inplace=True)
final.replace('month_12', required_date_range[11], inplace=True)
final.replace('month_1', required_date_range[0], inplace=True)
final.replace('month_2', required_date_range[1], inplace=True)
final.replace('month_3', required_date_range[2], inplace=True)
final.replace('month_4', required_date_range[3], inplace=True)
final.replace('month_5', required_date_range[4], inplace=True)
final.replace('month_6', required_date_range[5], inplace=True)
final.replace('month_7', required_date_range[6], inplace=True)
final.replace('month_8', required_date_range[7], inplace=True)
final.replace('month_9', required_date_range[8], inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could construct a dict and then call `map` on the split column str:

```
In [27]:
d = dict(zip([str(x) for x in range(1,13)], required_date_range))
d

Out[27]:
{'1': '2015-03-01',
 '10': '2015-12-01',
 '11': '2016-01-01',
 '12': '2016-02-01',
 '2': '2015-04-01',
 '3': '2015-05-01',
 '4': '2015-06-01',
 '5': '2015-07-01',
 '6': '2015-08-01',
 '7': '2015-09-01',
 '8': '2015-10-01',
 '9': '2015-11-01'}

In [26]:
df.columns = df.columns.to_series().str.rsplit('_').str[1].map(d) + '_' + df.columns.to_series().str.rsplit('_').str[-1]
df.columns

Out[26]:
Index(['2015-03-01_Sign', '2015-04-01_Sign', '2015-05-01_Sign',
       '2015-06-01_Sign', '2015-07-01_Sign', '2015-08-01_Sign',
       '2015-09-01_Sign', '2015-10-01_Sign', '2015-11-01_Sign',
       '2015-12-01_Sign', '2016-01-01_Sign', '2016-02-01_Sign',
       '2015-03-01_Actual', '2015-04-01_Actual', '2015-05-01_Actual',
       '2015-06-01_Actual', '2015-07-01_Actual', '2015-08-01_Actual',
       '2015-09-01_Actual', '2015-10-01_Actual', '2015-11-01_Actual',
       '2015-12-01_Actual', '2016-01-01_Actual', '2016-02-01_Actual',
       '2015-03-01_Target', '2015-04-01_Target', '2015-05-01_Target',
       '2015-06-01_Target', '2015-07-01_Target', '2015-08-01_Target',
       '2015-09-01_Target', '2015-10-01_Target', '2015-11-01_Target',
       '2015-12-01_Target', '2016-01-01_Target', '2016-02-01_Target'],
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: This works great, thanks. I need to add an IF statement though because some columns (I didn't list them) actually have two underscores. 

month_12_SSI_Target
month_12_SSI_Delta
month_12_SSI_Potential

Is there a way to do something like IF final.columns.contains('SSI'):

Comment: Use  .str.contains to do that

Comment: All set now. It worked and I was able to do it for several files in a row with no issues. Cool

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import product

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 12 * 3), columns=['month_' + str(c[0]) + '_' + c[1] for c in product(range(1, 13), ['Sign', 'Actual', 'Target'])])
```

First create a mapping to the relevant months.

```
mapping = {'month_' + str(n): date for n, date in enumerate(required_date_range, 1)}

>>> mapping
{'month_1': '2015-03-01',
 'month_10': '2015-12-01',
 'month_11': '2016-01-01',
 'month_12': '2016-02-01',
 'month_2': '2015-04-01',
 'month_3': '2015-05-01',
 'month_4': '2015-06-01',
 'month_5': '2015-07-01',
 'month_6': '2015-08-01',
 'month_7': '2015-09-01',
 'month_8': '2015-10-01',
 'month_9': '2015-11-01'}
```

Then reassign columns, joining the mapped month (e.g. '2016-02-01') to the rest of the column name.  This was done using a list comprehension.

```
df.columns = [mapping.get(c[:c.find('_', 6)]) + c[c.find('_', 6):] for c in cols]

>>> df.columns.tolist()
['2015-03-01_Sign',
 '2015-04-01_Sign',
 '2015-05-01_Sign',
 '2015-06-01_Sign',
 '2015-07-01_Sign',
 '2015-08-01_Sign',
 '2015-09-01_Sign',
 '2015-10-01_Sign',
 '2015-11-01_Sign',
 '2015-12-01_Sign',
 '2016-01-01_Sign',
 '2016-02-01_Sign',
 '2015-03-01_Actual',
 '2015-04-01_Actual',
 '2015-05-01_Actual',
 '2015-06-01_Actual',
 '2015-07-01_Actual',
 '2015-08-01_Actual',
 '2015-09-01_Actual',
 '2015-10-01_Actual',
 '2015-11-01_Actual',
 '2015-12-01_Actual',
 '2016-01-01_Actual',
 '2016-02-01_Actual',
 '2015-03-01_Target',
 '2015-04-01_Target',
 '2015-05-01_Target',
 '2015-06-01_Target',
 '2015-07-01_Target',
 '2015-08-01_Target',
 '2015-09-01_Target',
 '2015-10-01_Target',
 '2015-11-01_Target',
 '2015-12-01_Target',
 '2016-01-01_Target',
 '2016-02-01_Target']
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use the .rename method instead of the .replace! For instance this code:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {'a': [1, 2, 4], 'b':[2,3,4],'c':[3,4,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df.rename(columns={'a': 'x1', 'b': 'x2'}, inplace=True)
```

Changes the 'a' and 'b' column title to 'x1' and 'x2' respectively.

The first line of the renaming code you have would change to:

```
final.rename(columns={'month_10':required_date_range[9]}, inplace=True)
```

In fact you could do every column in that one command by adding entries to the columns dictionary argument.

```
final.rename(columns={'month_10':required_date_range[9],
                      'month_9':required_date-range[8], ... (and so on) }, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Yeah, I had replace because I was actually doing (attempting) a loop. for col in df.columns: 

This didn't work though so I tried to do it one column at the time (like I pasted). Rename would work. I was hoping to not have to list out all of the columns one by one. Thanks.